# Log out restriction in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am making a website using javascript and php.

When the user logout from the website and then if he clicks the back button of browser then it goes to the previous state in which the user is logged in.

**1.** How can I restrict this?

**2.** Can it be done by sessions, or anything else?

Comment: This is unfortunately 3 questions in one. Please remove the others and focus on a single topic, demonstrating what you have tried and where the issue lies.

Comment: create a page for the logout and redirect to another page

Comment: Slow down and give [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a read. Apart from having multiple questions in one, they are all very broad, you need to decide on one question and then elaborate and include what you have tried yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)

Login.php:

```
...
$_SESSION["foo"] = $foo;
...
```

Logout.php:

```
...
unset($_SESSION["foo"]);
...
```

In `login.php` you will set the `SESSION`variable named `foo` (so the user is logged on). When he logs out, you will `destroy/unset` the `SESSION`variable named `foo`, so in each logged in page you may want to do a `if` statement checking if the `SESSION` variable is set(logged in) else (not logged in) then you can redirect the user to where ever you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

When user clicks back button the content is loaded from the browser cache and not from the server. That is why the it happens.

From my understanding, if the previous page processes some input from the same page, the browser shows an webpage expired notification.
Here is my example in php.

login.html

```
  <!doctype HTML>
  <html>
  <body>
  <form action="action.php" method="post">
   username <input type="text" name="uname"/>
   <input type="submit" value='login' />
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

action.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["uname"])){
 $user = $_POST["uname"];
 session_start();
 echo "welcome ". $user;
}
if(isset($_POST["logout"])){
 session_unset(); 
}

?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="action.php" method="post" >
<input type="hidden" name="logout" />
<input type="submit" value="logout" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

If user clicks backbutton after loging out browser shows webpage expired message.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have good with nice pleasure.

Please check this code may be help you.

File name: _32_session.php

```
<?php

session_start();

?>

<html>
    <body>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <label>Please enter your Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
        <input type="submit" name="Unset" value="Logout">
    </form>
    </body>

    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['Unset']))
        {
            session_destroy();
            header('Location:_32_session.php');

        }

        elseif(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
             $name = $_POST['name'];
            $_SESSION['name']=$name;

        }

        if(isset($_SESSION['name']))
        {
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Wellcome ".$_SESSION['name'];
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Wellcome Guest";
        }

    ?>

</html>
```

Use this code and check.

Regards,